# rich:fileUpload extrenal Clear button issue on IE8

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, richfaces

We are upgrading from jsf 1.2 to jsf 2.

We are using apache myfaces 2.1 and rich faces 4.3.5

We are facing below issue for rich:fileUplaod.
Below is the code :

```
<h:form id="loadUsersForm">


 <h:panelGrid columns="1">

    <rich:fileUpload id="upload" 
                     acceptedTypes="csv"
                     immediateUpload="true" 
                     maxFilesQuantity="1" 
                     listHeight="0px" 
                     fileUploadListener="#{bean.uploadFile}"
                     addLabel="Ad File" 
                     uploadLabel="Upload">

            <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" 
                      execute="@this" 
                      render="fText,clearButton" />
            <f:facet name="progress">
                <rich:progressBar style="display:none;"/>
            </f:facet>

    </rich:fileUpload>

    <h:commandButton id="clearButton" 
                     action="#{bean.clear}"  
                     onclick="#{rich:component('upload')}.clear();" 
                     value="Clear" />
 <h:panelGrid/>

</h:form>
```

As shown in above code , we are using another button to clear uploaded file . 
The below issue is only observed on IE8 (with its compatibity view mode turned on ):

1)When clear button is clicked ,  for onlick script, `#{rich:component('upload')}.clear();` the IE console gives error as : `Object doesn't support this property or method` and action method is not called . When same button is clicked again , action method is called sccessfully.

2)When this script is removed , this error is not observed. But same behaviour for action method is observed .The action method is called only when clear button is clicked twice.

Has anybody came across such an issue ? 
Can anyone please help in resolving this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The fileUpload in 4.3.x doesn't have the `clear()` method, as the error tells you. Use `removeAllItems()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try above fix and update the post. Meanwhile , is there any link for document explaining changed java script methods for Rich Faces 4.3 ?

Comment: We have a [migration guide](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration), but I can't guarantee that everything is covered.